# Where do the system calls after execve in strace come from? And what are they doing?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, strace

I am currently writing a program that monitors process system calls, and I need to know more about the underlying mechanisms of how processes are run.

Here is `runner.c`:

```
>cat runner.c
#include "headers.h"
#include "helpers.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
        printf("Hello World\n");
        execlp("echo", "echo", "Runner", (char*)NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

If I do `strace runner`, the first call is the execve that runs the program, but where do all the calls come from between the execve and the actual `write` that prints `Hello World`?

```
>strace runner
execve("/media/sf_19-20/6CCS3PRJ/MVEE/c playground/runner", ["runner"], 0x7ffc61503c40 /* 42 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x556111e53000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=79994, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 79994, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fcdf2470000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320l\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1820104, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fcdf24b3000
mmap(NULL, 1832568, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fcdf22b0000
mprotect(0x7fcdf22d5000, 1642496, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fcdf22d5000, 1339392, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7fcdf22d5000
mmap(0x7fcdf241c000, 299008, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16c000) = 0x7fcdf241c000
mmap(0x7fcdf2466000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b5000) = 0x7fcdf2466000
mmap(0x7fcdf246c000, 13944, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fcdf246c000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fcdf24b4500) = 0
mprotect(0x7fcdf2466000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x556110910000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fcdf24af000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fcdf2470000, 79994)           = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x556111e53000
brk(0x556111e74000)                     = 0x556111e74000
write(1, "Hello World\n", 12Hello World
)           = 12
execve("echo", ["echo", "Runner"], 0x7ffcd1a7f358 /* 42 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/local/sbin/echo", ["echo", "Runner"], 0x7ffcd1a7f358 /* 42 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/local/bin/echo", ["echo", "Runner"], 0x7ffcd1a7f358 /* 42 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/sbin/echo", ["echo", "Runner"], 0x7ffcd1a7f358 /* 42 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["echo", "Runner"], 0x7ffcd1a7f358 /* 42 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5589c0f4e000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=79994, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 79994, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49b1f0000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320l\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1820104, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd49b237000
mmap(NULL, 1832568, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49b030000
mprotect(0x7fd49b055000, 1642496, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fd49b055000, 1339392, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7fd49b055000
mmap(0x7fd49b19c000, 299008, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16c000) = 0x7fd49b19c000
mmap(0x7fd49b1e6000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b5000) = 0x7fd49b1e6000
mmap(0x7fd49b1ec000, 13944, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd49b1ec000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fd49b238580) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd49b1e6000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x5589bf871000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd49b22f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fd49b1f0000, 79994)           = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5589c0f4e000
brk(0x5589c0f6f000)                     = 0x5589c0f6f000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2995, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2995
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=368, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 368, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49b200000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26402, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 26402, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49b1f8000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 23, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49b1f0000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_TELEPHONE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=59, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 59, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49b028000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_ADDRESS", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=167, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 167, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49b020000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_NAME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=77, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 77, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49b018000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_PAPER", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 34, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49b010000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=57, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 57, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49b008000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MONETARY", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=286, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 286, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49b000000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2586242, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2586242, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49ad88000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_TIME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3284, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3284, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49ad80000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_NUMERIC", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=54, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 54, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49ad78000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=337024, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 337024, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd49ad20000
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}) = 0
write(1, "Runner\n", 7Runner
)                 = 7
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

I know that execve sets up all the memory for the new process and stuff like that (I don't know all of the specifics yet though), but where is the code that makes these system calls after `execve` is run? I would like to see the source code.

Pretty much the exact same calls are made after the second `execve` as well. I presume that the kernel loads this code into the memory of the process and it gets run after the call returns.

And what exactly is this code doing?

Thanks.

Comment: Too short for a real answer: it's the dynamic linker and libc.

Comment: Well that doesn't answer my questions, and it doesn't really help either. I asked for where is the code that makes these calls, and what exactly is this code doing? Your comment basically boils down to "Google dynamic linker and libc". I'm sure you could go into more detail if you know more.